# What is the issue when WCF service is called from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, wcf, soap

Soap message send to the WCFservice is given:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ExecuteMobileEvent xmlns="http://address/2014/10">

  <sRequestStream>
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Request>          
      <Params>            
        <LoginData UserId='abdul' Password='admin' UserType='D'/>            
      </Params>          
    </Request>        
  </sRequestStream>

  <lEventId>1000</lEventId>
  <lActorId>10</lActorId>
  <lClientId>1</lClientId>
  </ExecuteMobileEvent>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The response to this soap message is given below:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">
        a:DeserializationFailed
      </faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">
        The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ExecuteMobileEvent'. No characters can appear before the XML declaration. Line 9, position 18.
      </faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
          <InnerException>
            <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
            <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
            <Message>
              No characters can appear before the XML declaration. Line 9, position 18.
```

Could any one find what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blank at the start of the message. The error message says so quite clearly:

> No characters can appear before the XML declaration.

And I'm pretty sure that this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Does not belong in line 9 either.

Fix your SOAP message.

Do you actually plan to send userId and plaintext password over unencrypted channels in SOAP? You should really get someone that knows how to do webservices.

Comment: And +1 for the security comment too.

Comment: I changed the line and new message is displaying The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'ExecuteMobileEvent'. End element 'sRequestStream' from namespace 'http://address/2014/10' expected. Found element 'Request' from namespace 'http://address/2014/10'. Line 9, position 26.

Comment: Thanks Ruskin for your quick response

Comment: Your message doesn't seem to be what the service expects. Why don't you just use a tool like SOAPUI to let someone generate a message that understands the service? Without seeing the service, it's almost impossible to tell what you did wrong when crafting the message (manually I guess).

Comment: I don't see what that changes. Every service that someone develops is only accessible from a local network until done. We cannot help you because we don't know this service. You obviously crafted the soap message wrong. Either find a tool that does a better job for you (SoapUI is free and works ok) or post the service (code or WSDL) so we can check ourselfs.